# Second instance of Wildfly trying to start

Tags: java, wildfly

We use Wildfly 10.1.0.Final here and over the last few days some curious behavior has manifested. First it was one user, but now over the course of the last few days, it's up to four users.

In house, we typically run Wildfly through standalone.bat on Windows (although I use mine as a service, and on Ubuntu).

The behavior is that after about an hour, a second instance of Wildfly attempts to start. These users do not have it installed as a service; it's run purely through the script. Sometimes it takes about two hours, but it's typically one. What we'll see in the log is that the `Configured system properties:` line prints in the log, followed by the usual startup information. There is no previous shutdown, no restart; the existing Java process controlling Wildfly is still running. A second whole Java process is being started. It gets about 1 second into the startup process, at which point Undertow sees the 8080 port is already in use, and then stops. What happens though, is that the two instances seem to start stepping all over each other and the end result is that both Java processes are still running, and our application is undeployed, with accompanying `.undeployed` file.

I have searched around but have turned up nothing. Are there any facilities in Wildfly to try and troubleshoot this? Is there a way to determine why Wildfly was started (to try and see why the second instance is popping up)? I think it's unlikely to be anything in our code that makes a whole new second Java process pop up, because we don't have any such thing coded in, but I'm open to possibilities.

**EDIT:** To add a detail, I just noticed that when this happens, while the original process was started by the logged in user (as shown in Windows Task Manager), the second process was started by the `SYSTEM` user. Keep in mind that Wildfly was not installed as a service (i.e. it's not erroneous service startup).

Comment: You are running on Windows. Have you tried checking the process tree using Process Explorer from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite ? That would not only give you an idea of the user starting the process but actually the starting process (unless that terminated).